# there is a in if statement when trying to match with regex

Tags: javascript

The script stopped running and I'm getting script error "Cannot read property '1' of null" when the regex doesn't match, when I tried to use it in an if statement. How do I fix this, if I want to use it in the if statement?

```
var titleDescription = "doesNotMatchThis";
var tempMatch = titleDescription.match(/(matchThis)/i);
if (tempMatch[1]) { //do this }
else { //do that }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [String.match()'s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value):

> If the string matches the expression, it will return an Array
>   containing the entire matched string as the first element, followed by
>   any results captured in parentheses. **If there were no matches, null is
>   returned.**

You can simply test for whether is `tempMatch` is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). If it is, then all sub-matches will be as well:

```js
var titleDescription = 'doesNotMatchThat';
var tempMatch = titleDescription.match(/(matchThis)/i);
if (tempMatch) {
  console.log('matched');
} else {
  console.log('not matched');
}
```

Comment: What...? I used to use PHP and I think you can't just use it in the if statement without the [] as well.

Comment: @frosty In PHP, you would probably use `preg_match` which returns a number of matches. Or do you mean in PHP in general? I'm not sure to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)ness of `tempMatch` first, for non matching strings.

```
if (tempMatch && tempMatch[1]) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, isn't it?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy MDN thinks it is - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: I would personally write it [`truthiness`](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Truthiness), or would try to reformulate the sentence to use the word `truthy` instead as linked in the comment above. But well, these are just details :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `test()` method. It returns `true` or `false` based on matched or not.

```
var regex1 = RegExp('foo*');
var regex2 = RegExp('foo*','g');
var str1 = 'table football';

console.log(regex1.test(str1));
// expected output: true
```

Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).